# Kafka using Docker for production clusters

Tags: linux, docker, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

We need to build a Kafka production cluster with 3-5 nodes in cluster ,

We have the following options:

1. Kafka in Docker containers (Kafka cluster include zookeeper and schema registry on each node)
2. Kafka cluster not using docker (Kafka cluster include zookeeper and schema registry on each node)

Since we are talking on production cluster we need good performance as we have high read/write to disks (disk size is 10T), good IO performance, etc.

**So does Kafka using Docker meet the requirements for productions clusters?**

more info - https://www.infoq.com/articles/apache-kafka-best-practices-to-optimize-your-deployment/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done, sure. I have no personal experience with it, but if you don't otherwise have experience managing other stateful containers, I'd suggest avoiding it.

As far as "getting started" with Kafka in containers, Kubernetes is the most documented way, and Strimzi (free, optional commercial support by Lightbend) or Confluent Operator (commercial support by Confluent) can make this easy when using Kubernetes or Openshift. Or DC/OS offers a Kafka service over Mesos/Marathon. If you don't already have any of these services, then I think it's apparent that you should favor not using containers.

Bare metal or virtualized deployments would be much easier to maintain than hand-deployed containerized ones, from what I have experienced. Particularly for logging, metric gathering, and statically assigned Kafka listener mappings over the network. Confluent provides Ansible scripts for doing deployments to such environments

---

That isn't to say there's companies that have been successful at it, or at least tried. IBM, RedHat, and Shopify immediately pop up in my searches, for example

Here's a few talk about things to consider when Kafka is in containers 
https://www.confluent.io/kafka-summit-london18/kafka-in-containers-in-docker-in-kubernetes-in-the-cloud

https://kafka-summit.org/sessions/running-kafka-kubernetes-practical-guide/

Comment: still not get answer - dose kafka using docker is bad choice against not using docker ( when we are talking about productions clusters )

Comment: There are several companies using Kafka containers in production, but I'm only aware of those in Kubernetes. Docker itself in production has several limitations that are broader than just Kafka

Comment: you said - "Docker itself has several limitations that are broader than just Kafka" , please explain then -?

Comment: or maybe - do you know if some company using kafka doker for production cluster?

Comment: For starters, putting a memory limited JVM inside of a memory limited container rather than giving access to a full dedicated OS is one issue. Then networking bridges are a pain to deal with, for example handling SSL between host applications and the container services, or just service discovery. Then most containers run as root, potentially exposing some bad attack vectors. If a stateful container is killed, it must be restarted with the same network and storage mappings, otherwise it's services will start from scratch and the IP changes... There's plenty of blogs giving pros/cons of Docker

Comment: so after I read your last note - I get the impression that kafka not using docker have better performce aspect then kafka using docker ( maybe we can use kafka using docker for labs etc and not production cluster that need very high performance )

Comment: Performance degradation is certainly a factor, yes. The reason I find that you'd want to containerize one thing is because other things are also containerized and that's just the way the company deploys things. Therefore, Kafka brokers would possibly be running on the same machines as 50 other microservices, all using the same external disks and network interfaces... It's far better to give Kafka dedicated spinning disks (which could be done with resource tag constraints, but that's besides the point)

Comment: about you last note - lets say we are using only kafka + zookeeper + schema registry on each container on dedicated machines , without any other services , is it change something ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201520/discussion-between-jessica-and-cricket-007).